# calculate age based on id

Tags: java, if-statement

public int  payment(){

```
        int Carpayment;
        int hour;
        String type;
        
        if (type == "MyVi")
            Carpayment = 10 * hour;
        else 
            if (type == "Iswara")
                Carpayment = 15 * hour;
        else 
            if (type == "Waja")
                Carpayment = 20 * hour;
        else 
            if (type == "Vios")
                Carpayment = 25 * hour;
        else 
            if (type == "Civic")
                Carpayment = 30 * hour; 
        
        return Carpayment;
     }
```

when i run this code.. error Carpayment might have not been initialized

Comment: You should **not** compare `String`s with `==`, use `equals` for that. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

Some Rectifications you can do

1. Comparing **type == "MyVi"** , you should not compare String's with == operator because it will compare for object i.e hashcode comparison.
   You should use **type.equals("MyVi");**
2. You should not use local variables to calculate the car payment as they need to be initialized so you should pass them to the payment method or use them as an **instance variable.**

   ```
   public int payment(int Carpayment,int hour,String type){

       //int Carpayment;
       //int hour;
       //String type;

       if (type == "MyVi")
           Carpayment = 10 * hour;
       else 
           if (type == "Iswara")
               Carpayment = 15 * hour;
       else 
           if (type == "Waja")
               Carpayment = 20 * hour;
       else 
           if (type == "Vios")
               Carpayment = 25 * hour;
       else 
           if (type == "Civic")
               Carpayment = 30 * hour; 

       return Carpayment;
    }
   ```

3.You can do something like this

```
    Class Car {
       int Carpayment;
       int hour;
       String type;
       Car(int hour,String type) {
       this.hour = hour;
       this.type = type;
       }
       public int payment(){

            if (type == "MyVi")
                Carpayment = 10 * hour;
            else 
                if (type == "Iswara")
                    Carpayment = 15 * hour;
            else 
                if (type == "Waja")
                    Carpayment = 20 * hour;
            else 
                if (type == "Vios")
                    Carpayment = 25 * hour;
            else 
                if (type == "Civic")
                    Carpayment = 30 * hour; 

            return Carpayment;
         }
       }
       Car civic_1 = new Car(4,"Civic");
       System.out.println(civic_1.payment());//Prints the Car payment to be done
```

Answer (score -1):

It is occurs because you do not have a last else clause. So than, you can pass for all ifs and do not enter and anyone. To solve this problem you can:

1. Initialise the Carpayment variable with a default value (better option in my opinion);

   ```
   public int  payment(){
    int Carpayment;
            int hour;
            String type;

    if (type == "MyVi")
        Carpayment = 10 * hour;
    else 
        if (type == "Iswara")
            Carpayment = 15 * hour;
    else 
        if (type == "Waja")
            Carpayment = 20 * hour;
    else 
        if (type == "Vios")
            Carpayment = 25 * hour;
    else 
        if (type == "Civic")
            Carpayment = 30 * hour; 

    return Carpayment;
   }
   ```

or

2. Put a last else clause in the last else if.

   ```
   public int  payment(){
    int Carpayment;
            int hour;
            String type;

    if (type == "MyVi")
        Carpayment = 10 * hour;
    else 
        if (type == "Iswara")
            Carpayment = 15 * hour;
    else 
        if (type == "Waja")
            Carpayment = 20 * hour;
    else 
        if (type == "Vios")
            Carpayment = 25 * hour;
    else 
        if (type == "Civic")
            Carpayment = 30 * hour;
    else 
      Carpayment = 0;

    return Carpayment;
   }
   ```